# Data from view to serializer in django rest api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am struggling with this problem for a while.

Ok here is my serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from happytourist.models import PointsInterestData

class PointsInterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer, serializers.Serializer):
    distance = serializers.IntegerField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        model = PointsInterestData
        fields = ('name', 'latitude', 'longtitude', 'distance')
        read_only_fields = fields

from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import PointsInterestSerializer
from happytourist.models import PointsInterestData

class PointsInterestList(generics.ListCreateAPIView, generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PointsInterestSerializer


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = PointsInterestData.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_latitude = request.POST.get('latitude')
        user_longtitude = request.POST.get('longtitude')
        radius = request.POST.get('radius')
        usergeodata = {'latitude': user_latitude, 'longtitude': user_longtitude, 'radius': radius}
        return usergeodata

    def get_coordinates(self):
        latitude = PointsInterestData.objects.model.latitude
        longtitude = PointsInterestData.objects.model.longtitude
        geodata = {"latitude": latitude, "longtitude": longtitude}
        return geodata
```

What I want to do is to change distance parameter in serializer according to the view. I need to write a function in view which result will be calculated distance (i know how to make this) and this result will be put into serializer (which i do not know how to make it)

Comment: A couple things to note is that you do not need to inherit from both ModelSerializer and Serializer. Also you will not be able to modify distance since you set the value to read only using  `read_only_fields = fields`. Also is distance a related field? One last thing are you using geodjango?

Comment: your question is not clear. in what action you want to do that? list or create? also in your create method, you are not creating anything, are you sure a simple post method that does some calculation on the user input is not what you really want?

Comment: The final distance value has not ben calculated yet. Lets presume that the value is equal to 1.     def distancecalc(): return 1. No i want to bind these result to distance value to serializer.

Answer (score 0):

all right this what I have done:

view:

class PointsInterestList(generics.ListCreateAPIView, generics.ListAPIView):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = PointsInterestData.objects.all()
    return queryset

def distancecalc():
    return 4

def get_serializer_context(self):
    distance_result = PointsInterestList.distancecalc()
    context = super(PointsInterestList, self).get_serializer_context()
    context.update({'distance': distance_result})
    return context

serializer_class = PointsInterestSerializer
```

serializer:

class PointsInterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer, serializers.Serializer):
    distance = serializers.SerializerMethodField(default=None)

```
def get_distance(self, obj):
    distance_view = self.context.get('distance')
    return distance_view

class Meta:
    model = PointsInterestData
    fields = ('name', 'latitude', 'longtitude', 'distance')
    read_only_fields = fields
```